# Type signature declaration of some operations with Church numerals

Tags: haskell, church-encoding

I was trying to implement Church numerals in Haskell. This is my code:

```
-- Church numerals in Haskell.
type Numeral a = (a -> a) -> (a -> a)

churchSucc :: Numeral a -> Numeral a
churchSucc n f = \x -> f (n f x)

-- Operations with Church numerals.
sum :: Numeral a -> Numeral a -> Numeral a
sum m n = m . churchSucc n

mult :: Numeral a -> Numeral a -> Numeral a
mult n m = n . m

-- Here comes the first problem
-- exp :: Numeral a -> Numeral a -> Numeral a
exp n m = m n

-- Convenience function to "numerify" a Church numeral.
add1 :: Integer -> Integer
add1 = (1 +)

numerify :: Numeral Integer -> Integer
numerify n = n add1 0

-- Here comes the second problem
toNumeral :: Integer -> Numeral Integer
toNumeral 0 = zero
toNumeral (x + 1) = churchSucc (toNumeral x)
```

My problem comes from exponentiation. If I declare the type signature of `toNumeral` and `exp`, the code doesn't compile. However, if I comment the type signature declarations, everything works fine. What would be the correct declarations for `toNumeral` and `exp`?

Comment: You can lookup them in GHCi or write `:: _` and make the compiler show the type for you.

Comment: Of course GHC will infer `exp :: a -> (a -> b) -> b`, which is not very helpful if you want to relate it to exponentiation of church numerals. It's correct, but it's general enough that it's hard to see how it lines up with what was intended.

Comment: Using a monotype for Church numerals might restrict their applicability. I'd consider using a polytype `type Numeral = forall a. (a->a)->a->a` using the needed extensions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason `exp` cannot be written the way you have it is that it involves passing a `Numeral` as argument to a `Numeral`. This requires having a `Numeral (a -> a)`, but you only have a `Numeral a`. You can write it as

```
exp :: Numeral a -> Numeral (a -> a) -> Numeral a
exp n m = m n
```

I don't see what's wrong with `toNumeral`, aside from the fact that patterns like `x + 1` should not be used.

```
toNumeral :: Integer -> Numeral a -- No need to restrict it to Integer
toNumeral 0 = \f v -> v
toNumeral x
  | x > 0 = churchSucc $ toNumeral $ x - 1
  | otherwise = error "negative argument"
```

Also, your `sum` is bugged, because `m . churchSucc n` is `m * (n + 1)`, so it should be:

```
sum :: Numeral a -> Numeral a -> Numeral a
sum m n f x = m f $ n f x -- Repeat f, n times on x, and then m more times.
```

However, church numerals are functions that work on *all* types. That is, `Numeral String` should not be different from `Numeral Integer`, because a `Numeral` shouldn't care what type it's working on. This is a *universal quantification*: `Numeral` is a function, for all types `a`, `(a -> a) -> (a -> a)`, which is written, with `RankNTypes`, as `type Numeral = forall a. (a -> a) -> (a -> a)`.

This makes sense: a church numeral is defined by how many times its function argument is repeated. `\f v -> v` calls `f` 0 times, so it is 0, `\f v -> f v` is 1, etc. Forcing a `Numeral` to work for all `a` makes sure that it can *only* do that. However, allowing a `Numeral` to care what type `f` and `v` have removes the restriction, and lets you write `(\f v -> "nope") :: Numeral String`, even though that clearly isn't a `Numeral`.

I would write this as

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}

type Numeral = forall a. (a -> a) -> (a -> a)

_0 :: Numeral
_0 _ x = x
-- The numerals can be defined inductively, with base case 0 and inductive step churchSucc
-- Therefore, it helps to have a _0 constant lying around

churchSucc :: Numeral -> Numeral
churchSucc n f x = f (n f x) -- Cleaner without lambdas everywhere

sum :: Numeral -> Numeral -> Numeral
sum m n f x = m f $ n f x

mult :: Numeral -> Numeral -> Numeral
mult n m = n . m

exp :: Numeral -> Numeral -> Numeral
exp n m = m n

numerify :: Numeral -> Integer
numerify n = n (1 +) 0

toNumeral :: Integer -> Numeral
toNumeral 0 = _0
toNumeral x
  | x > 0 = churchSucc $ toNumeral $ x - 1
  | otherwise = error "negative argument"
```

instead, which looks so much cleaner, and is less likely to run into roadblocks than the original.

Demo:

```
main = do out "5:" _5
          out "2:" _2
          out "0:" _0
          out "5^0:" $ exp _5 _0
          out "5 + 2:" $ sum _5 _2
          out "5 * 2:" $ mult _5 _2
          out "5^2:" $ exp _5 _2
          out "2^5:" $ exp _2 _5
          out "(0^2)^5:" $ exp (exp _0 _2) _5
       where _2 = toNumeral 2
             _5 = toNumeral 5
             out :: String -> Numeral -> IO () -- Needed to coax the inferencer
             out str n = putStrLn $ str ++ "\t" ++ (show $ numerify n)
```

Comment: At some point this will hit a wall due to impredicative types. If one plans to actually use such code for anything practical, one is better off with `newtype Numeral = Numeral (forall a. (a -> a) -> (a -> a))`. Of course the version in this answer is just as good for the purpose of demonstration/learning.

Comment: Here's a pile of things I threw together with this: https://repl.it/KVI1/4

Comment: Regarding sum, I had two versions, the one that you mention and the one I posted. I posted the second one because it looked more concise, however, I didn't realize it was wrong. Thanks for pointing that out and for the answer. BTW, I think the corrected version of sum (and using some of the tips you provided) could be: `sum2 :: Numeral ((a -> a) -> (a -> a)) -> Numeral a -> Numeral a
sum2 m n = m churchSucc n`. I agree in that your version looks more concise and the generality of the Church numerals though. Cheers!